# remove docker container remotely via ssh connection

Tags: docker, ssh

I'd like to run command remove docker container on remote host but got failed response

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.138.154.26 "docker rm `docker ps -a | grep 3000 | awk '{print $1}'`"
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
```

seem like I put an incorrect command of ssh with a nested shell command.
could you please help what command I can do that to remove in ssh??

Comment: The command in backticks is probably being interpreted on your side of the connection. Try using `xargs` instead... `docker ps -a | ... | xargs docker rm`

Comment: thank you for help. I got it as following your tip.